# Unable to right-align view using contraints

Tags: ios, ipad, nslayoutconstraint

I have a tableview that uses a custom UITableViewCell.  The cell contains a UILabel that needs to be right-aligned in the cell.

This is an iPad app.  I've designed the custom cell to fit in portrait orientation by default (768 width).  The issue is when the app rotates to landscape orientation that the UILabel does not stay on the right side.  I've even tested to ensure that the cell itself is stretching correctly to the width of the landscape orientation.

No matter what I do it seems that it wants to align relative to the left side only.  In the constraints in IB I select "Trailing Space to Superview" but it doesn't seem to do anything.  IB automatically sets Horizontal Space (651) as offset from the left side.  I am unable to delete this constraint.

Is this really that difficult to do or I am just missing something really obvious?

Comment: Are you setting the constraints in code or in IB? Is Autolayout on?

Comment: @CaptJak, IB only at this point.  Yes, constraints are turned on. Other constraints work properly.

Comment: So, if you give the label a trailing space to the cell, and a specific width, are you not able to delete the constraint to the left side?

Comment: I am not sure how to do this using only IB... But have you tried pinning the UILabel to the prototype cell? (i.e. Editor\Pin\Horizontal Spacing)

Comment: @rdelmar, is there any other way to add a trailing space other than "Trailing Space to Superview"?  This is what I tried but it doesn't do anything, i.e., no new constraints are added.

Comment: @CaptJak, Editor/Pin/Horizontal Spacing is disabled. I cannot choose this.

Comment: Adding it that way should work. The other way is to drag it to the right until you see the dotted blue line along its right edge. This gives you the standard distance to the right edge.

Comment: @rdelmar I drag it to the right and do see the various dotted lines. While doing this it sure seems like it will stick to the right, but as soon as I release it, it goes back to the leading horizontal space. Very frustrating.

Comment: I can't explain that, as I've never seen that behavior before. Can you post your app somewhere that I could take a look at it?

Comment: As a simple test I created a new xib, deleted the default UIView and dragged a TableViewCell onto the canvas.  I set the width to be 768 (iPad portrait width).  I dropped a UILabel onto the cell and dragged it to the right side.  The results were the same: Editor/Pin/Horizontal Spacing is disabled and Trailing Space to Superview does nothing.

Comment: I see what you mean. It works ok if you don't resize the cell, but as soon as you drag it wider or set the size to something bigger, it gives you this weird behavior. Also, even though I set the xib to be for iPad it gives you a table view cell that's 320 wide. This is definitely a bug in IB. Is there a reason you can't make the cell in a storyboard? It works fine there.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for confirming this. Yes, the default width is 320 regardless of whether I specify that this is for iPad. I'll try switching it to the storyboard. The only reason I chose to use a xib is because I've never used a custom cell from a storyboard before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36215/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-steve-barden)

Comment: This does seem to be a bug in IB.  I switched over to putting the cell directly in the tableview in the storyboard. Overall it's a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Take Cell IBoutlet on this way]

1.Add new file from ios/User interface/Empty.
2. Add tableview cell from objects and add label in it.
2.Give lable tag 1 plus Set alignment right (as show in below image)

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AzJH.png
```

Now in your tableview delegate method add below line

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *cellid =@"Cellid";

    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
    if(cell==nil){

        cell =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"cell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        //[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellid];

    }
    UILabel *celllabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    celllabel.text =@"Test label alignment";
    return cell;
}
```

It's perfectly work for me.